# ArgumentException in linq query when using char.isDigit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have following simplified linq query:

```
IQueryable<PersonListItemDbTemp> query =
    from pers in db.Person
    join pe in db.PersonExtra on pers.PersonID equals pe.PersonID into ppe
    from personExtra in ppe.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new PersonListItemDbTemp()
    {                                                                
        PersonnrAreDigits = pers.Personnr != null && pers.Personnr.All(p => char.IsDigit(p))
    };
return query;
```

where pers.Personnr is a string. I get following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
>   Parameternamn: input
>      vid System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.DbExpressionBuilder.BindAs(DbExpression input, String varName)
>      vid System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
>      vid

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: By the exception object names, I guess linq-to-entities and EF core, but yeah, OP should tag it :-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter this is LINQ-to-Entities and EF6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is a little odd, meaning that there might be a bug in EF here but the issue is still clear:

EF does not know how to translate `string.All(p => char.IsDigit(p))` to SQL.

You might be able to use the helpers in [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
PersonnrAreDigits = 
        //pers.Personnr != null && 
        //pers.Personnr.All(p => char.IsDigit(p))
        SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(pers.PersonNr) == 1
```